# Can we close Markdown rendering bugs against a related but maybe not fitting duplicate

Tags: discussion, meta, canonical, markdown-rendering

We currently have 27 open bug reports for [markdown rendering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmarkdown-rendering%5D+%5Bbug%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3A0+-%5Bstatus*%5D+answers%3A0) and most of those are of the type:

> The preview shows X, after posting it shows Y

where X and Y can be any markdown/html that you can dream-up.

One of the latest incarnations was [Stack Overflow URLs in double quotes in answers are not replaced by the name of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419387) where I decided it might be better to lump similar bugs together so after some research I duplicate voted against [Editor preview disagrees on link title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345847/editor-preview-disagrees-on-link-title).

After the community review was complete the post was indeed closed as a duplicate. One user voted to leave open, 3 others voted to close. In the comments I was pinged for selecting a not fitting duplicate and the alternative of leaving the bug report simply open might be a better option.

I'm not sure now what is better. Do we help the poor SE developer that has to fix all these bugs by linking but not closing such reports or do we start closing against a reasonable duplicate target? In that case which target would that be?

Comment: If you go to [meta.se] you'll probably find more than 27 open bug reports on markdown tables alone...

Comment: @Larnu .... I didn't even dare going there ;)

Comment: or we could have the devs start closing the markdown rendering bugs :upside_down:

Comment: I would prefer to treat bug reports similar to tickets like in Jira or GitHub. We already have status tags similar to a ticket workflow and the usual housekeeping/clean up step of closing related reports as duplicate should be kept as well. This enables us and the developers to check on the status of certain bugs and the software in general. SE staff already update tags on some bug reports when they have been resolved, but I rarely see them searching for all similar reports for the same issue to update those as well. So we would end up with open reports for an already fixed bug.

Comment: While the two linked questions are related wrt. being issues that deal with URLs, Markdown, and double-quotes, my expectation is that these two are two separate bugs. The two show opposite issues wrt. if it's properly rendered in the preview or on the server. [The recently closed question](/q/419387) is about what happens in the SE specific rendering of SE post/question titles from just a URL, while the [duplicate target](/q/345847) is about straight CommonMark Markdown conversion to HTML. The parsing for those are almost certainly separate, with the URL->SE post likely a pre-processing step.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

##### Close as a duplicate if you reasonably believe it's the same bug

In general, we should close bug reports as duplicates, if and only if we reasonably believe they are caused by the same bug, not the same class of bugs.

The goal with such reports is to get bug reports into the hands of Stack Exchange developers. If we end up closing something that's actually a different bug as a duplicate of some other bug, then it's likely that SE developers will never be informed about the bug, until the developers are all done with fixing that area of the code and someone re-posts a bug report, or otherwise indicates that the original bug report, which was closed as a duplicate, wasn't actually fixed. We don't need to be paranoid about being *sure* it's the same bug for the duplicate, just use our best judgement. Put yourself in the position of being the developer receiving the bug reports. What would you want to see, assuming the only things which you actually see are questions which are not marked as duplicates and which at some point had a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag?

##### Handling reports of actual CommonMark Markdown rendering differences between preview and server-side

It *is* frustrating that there are so many issues and bug report questions regarding the differences between the two implementations of Markdown conversion which Stack Overflow uses. While it would be nice to have all of these issues organized into one place, that's really the job of tags. For these bugs, we have the [markdown-rendering](/questions/tagged/markdown-rendering) tag.

Stack Exchange has consistently stated that they want bugs in separate questions, not rolled up into a single question. The only times they've *temporarily* wanted organization other than that has been when their developers are actively working on some area of the site and specifically ask for bugs/issues to be included as answers to a question they post for that purpose. When the developers are done, Stack Exchange typically asks for reports to return to the one question per bug format, even that unresolved bugs which were initially reported as an answer each be reposted as a new question, because bug reports as questions is what ties into their ticketing system.

##### The specific example linked in this question appears to be two different bugs, IMO

While the two linked questions are related with respect to being issues that deal with URLs, Markdown, and double-quotes, my expectation is that these are actually two separate bugs, because:

- The two reports show opposite issues with respect to if it's properly rendered in the preview or on the server.
- [The recently closed question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419387/3773011) is about what happens in the SE specific rendering of SE post/question titles from just a URL, while the [duplicate target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345847/3773011) is about straight CommonMark Markdown conversion to HTML. The parsing for those two things are almost certainly separate, with the URL➞SE post title conversion likely a pre-processing step.

I've reopened that question, [verified the bug exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380624/271271), and added the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to get it into Stack Exchange's ticketing system. However, I believe I've seen a question about that bug in the past, either on MSO or MSE, so it's likely an actual duplicate, or at least a cross-site duplicate. Obviously, if an actual duplicate on MSO is found, then it should be re-closed.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we should close these posts unless there are other reasons to do so (e.g. report is unclear, not reproducible, exact duplicate, etc.– the normal stuff).

Duplicates exist to aggregate information– to pool answers and discussion and related information regarding the same question/ topic together in one place, since that makes it all easier to find.

Closing a bug report against a related *but different in key ways* bug report doesn't serve anyone in a way I can come up with; if anything, it just obscures the bug that gets closed, making it harder to find in the future.

I realize we're talking about Markdown preview & renderer bugs, which historically haven't gotten much love, but they're still valid bug reports. I don't see why we shouldn't treat them as such and let them stay open.