# Where can I report outdated links in the Help Center?

Tags: bug, markdown, help-center

On https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#need-more-detail, section **Need more Detail?** links to https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/.

The current version is `0.30` as described on https://spec.commonmark.org/.

Links to the current version are https://spec.commonmark.org/current/ and https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/.

Comment: Just because 0.30 is the newest doesn't mean SO has implemented it

Comment: @Zoe - So linking to 0.29 implies that version had been implemented?

Comment: To the extent one can say [SO has implemented markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419389/6296561), probably. But I have no clue what version of the spec they're running on

Comment: Slight note: The `/editing-help` page isn't actually part of the Help Center. It's a separate page that only devs can update (CMs can't edit it directly like we can with the Help Center).

Comment: Also, to preempt the question: I have no idea what version of CommonMark we implement, or if we list that anywhere... (I've found [this diff for the changes between 0.29 and 0.30](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/changes.html), and [this changelog](https://spec.commonmark.org/changelog.txt) - but which are the main changes that we would/should be implementing if we haven't already?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange [switched to CommonMark around June 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/241919). At that time, 0.29 (2019-04-06) was the latest version available, long before 0.30 (2021-06-19) was released.

As far as I know, Stack Exchange hasn't updated the CommonMark since then, so 0.29 is the right version (until proven otherwise).